# TIBCO Active Matrix password field no longer exists?

Tags: passwords, tibco, automated-deploy

After I depoly my application to Tibco ActiveMatrix Administrator, I go to properties and the property type is now changed to 'string' even though I made it as 'password' type. (Oh, but it is then encrypted like "#!jZ8MsfxWv2PCwTMAngz67w==") Stroing as string with encrypted value is fine, but if I change the value (For example, password 123 to 456), it is not encrypted anymore

Here are my questions..

1) Does Password type field not exist anymore in TIBCO ActiveMatrix Administrator version 3.2.0?

2) If you have **any experience on automated build** using TFS, what I meant by 'changing property' was property file in my script folder. My archive, ear, daa file stores that as password type, but it is changed to 'string' type automatically if I depoly to TIBCOM AMX Administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Administrator supports changing passwords. You will see like this. 
   [image: password-administrator-tibco]
2. If you want to change/update the password via scripts - you will have to encrypt the password. You can use the obfuscate.exe in the /bin folder. Read up on this in the TRA documentation.

Also of interest might be the "Working with Passwords" section in the TRA Scripting Deployment guide.